# Count from 1 to 10 in column 1 then move to next Column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to create a loop that starts in Column 1 counts to 10, then move to next column then count from 11 to 20

Please assist? I have tried substituting the R and C values with the LR and LC, but all it puts out is the first Column. Here is my code:

```
Sub counter()

 Dim R as Integer
 Dim C as Integer
 Dim LR as Long
 Dim LC as Long
 Dim T as Integer

LR = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 

T = 1

For R = 1 To 10
 For C = 1 To 10
  Cells(R,C).value = T
  T = T + 1
 Next C
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: The code works fine as is but populates by row rather than by column.  To populate by column, change Cells(R,C) to Cells(C,R) (or reverse the order of R and C in the for loops).

Comment: The formula `=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(10,10))` will create a 10x10 grid counting 1 to 10 in column 1, 11 to 20 in column 2, etc.

Comment: The formula `=WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(20),10)` will also give you your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean this:

```
Sub test()
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim i As Long

'starting row and column
R = 1
C = 1

For i = 1 To 20 Step 1
    Cells(R, C) = i
    R = R + 1
    
    If i / 10 = Int(10 / 10) Then
        C = C + 1
        R = 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

The code will restart R to first row and switch column every 10 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either

a) switch your `R`and `C` variable within `Cells(R,C)` to `Cells(C,R)`.

b) switch the loop order:

```vb
For R = 1 To 10
 For C = 1 To 10
  Cells(C, R).Value = T
  T = T + 1
  If T > 100 Then Exit Sub     'Exit when columns are filled
  Next C
Next R
```

Don't forget to exit your sub when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general way to run from 1 to n and put the results in a two-dimensional array (pseudo-code):

```
for i=1 to n
  a[i mod 10, i div 10] = i
next i
```

Have fun